# Latest iPhone iOS Mail app client size attachment size limit

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

Our Exchange Server with ActiveSync used by mobile clients has a 300 MB attachment limit.

We noticed that the Mail app on the latest iPhone removes attachments over a certain size (20 Mb??) before sending emails.

Other software (ex. AquaMail on Android) manages to send attachments up to 80 MB with the same email account.

We are 100% sure there are no iPhone specific smaller limits on the server side.

Does anyone know where to find the official maximum attachment size usable by the Mail app on iPhone?

I found this - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202305 - but that's specific to iCloud mail accounts

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Latest can include betas here, so you might get better answers if you ask about a named / specific iOS version or build.

Comment: By 'latest' iPhone, I'm assuming it is running iOS 12.x. I don't believe the iPhone itself would impose any attachment restriction. Is this restriction happening on one specific model of iPhone when compared with other models?

Comment: hello iOS version is 12.1.4 , I am quite confident restriction is client side because other mail clients can attach bigger files,  also we do not discriminate different activesync devices.

Comment: Is it ANY iPhone that has this problem, or a specific model of iPhone?

Comment: today I tried with an iphone 8 ,I had 2 other people test with theirs  same behaviour , I'll ask for their models thanks

Comment: as an update to this  we experience the same behaviour both on iphone 6 and 8 with IOS 12.1.4    does anyone know if attachment removal is to be expected on mail ?